# Element Exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to execute this code and it shows 'NoSuchElementException' this error. 
So can anyone help me for this ?

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver= webdriver.Chrome()

page=driver.get("http://www.awgp.org")
banner_tell=driver.find_element_by_Link_text('Tell Me More')
banner_tell.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to do is give link text in uppercase but this link is dynamic as the banner auto-slides to the next one.

You should come up with another locator to click on exactly the locator you want to click. Otherwise you might get `ElementNotVisibleException` if the banner is changed.

```
banner_tell=driver.find_element_by_link_text('TELL ME MORE')
```

Comment: `find_element_by_link_text()` returns visible elemens only, so you will not  get `ElementNotVisibleException` anyway... Also yes, `'TELL ME MORE'` should be used as this is exactly how link text appears on page (+1)

Comment: @Andersson- Thanks! The links are dynamic & their display attribute is set to `none` when the next banner is displayed. So, if the banner is changed before it is clicked, it would give the exception.

Comment: Yep, but if link is not visible it won't be found by `find_element_by_link_text()` so `NoSuchElementException` should be raised instead of `ElementNotVisibleException`...

Comment: Thanks @Amit. 'TELL ME MORE' works fine as it find the text in whole page which i was trying find the link in the banner.

Answer (score 0):

try with xpath

```
banner_tell= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'TELL ME MORE')]")
```

Comment: I am unable to locate element with xpath.

banner_tell= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@text,'TELL ME MORE')]")

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were almost near however the `function()` should have been :

```
find_element_by_link_text()
```

To click on the button with text as **TELL ME MORE** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) clause [`element_to_be_clickable`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) as follows :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "TELL ME MORE"))).click()
```